# How to check if a directory has an s3fs mount in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, s3fs

I'm trying to create a script which runs every time my ec2 instance starts up. It currently has a directory used to mount an s3 bucket: `/s3mnt`

In the script, I want to check if there is a mount on that directory, and perform a certain set of actions. if there is not a mount, i want to create one (i know the command for this) and then execute the same set of actions as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `mountpoint` on `/s3mnt`.  Internally this compares the stat device output of `/s3mnt` and `/s3mnt/..`.